# Somebody know best way how to controll Meteor.methods result from client-Side

Tags: meteor

I just wonder about Meteor.methods result stub. When i used Meteor.call, i tried handle result set but when result set out of range from Meteor.call area that return undefined. So I think if i use Session it can be solve. but sometime that way isn't work. So, if you guys, have you know best way to controll that topic, let me know your solutions!!

---

Thank you for comment, but I can't split up my logic. Because i want take javaScript library module from our old project-code. It had handle front-end of jQuery by html context for iframe. FirstTime, i tried figured out by use just iframe tag. but it had made issue for cross-domain. So i tried found solution about cross-domain on Meteor, but anywhere no solution. Therefore, i thinking how to solve it that issue and then i decided used Meteor.http! That was successed tool html.content from server-side and inside block of the callback function from client-side. but i can't hand over result out of callback function. i should give result of methods(iframe html content)  to our old javascript-code... that's why i try that way! Any idea about this? i include javascript-code, it will help understanding.

---

...

```
drawSvg2: function(){

            var objIFrame   = $("#iFrame_"+m.canvasIdx()).contents();
            var objList     = objIFrame.find('.page');
            var len         = objList.length;

            for (i=0; i<len; i++){
                var obj = objList[i];
                var children = obj.children;   //childNodes;

                var num = 0;
                for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
                    var children2 = children[k].children;

                    for (var j = 0; j < children2.length; j++) {
                        if(children2[j].children[0].nodeName == "P"){
                            m.textArray(num, new Object());
                            c.canvasFetch(children[k], children2[j], "", m.textArray()[num], num);
                        }else{
                            m.textArray(num, new Object());
                            c.canvasFetch(children[k], children2[j], children2[j].children[0], m.textArray()[num], num);
                        }
                        num++;
                    }
                }
            }
            v.drawSvg3();
        },
```

...

That is huge function and handled front-end by jQuery, So i can't put inside Meteor.methods..

Answer (score 0):

The way to use Meteor.call:

```
Meteor.call('methodName', param1Value, param2Value,..., function (error, result) { ... } );
```

The last parameter is a callback.  Meteor invokes this callback function when the result is ready.  Inside the body of the callback function, you can do whatever you want with the result.  Why do you need to return this result to the calling function?  Can you split up the logic so that it invoke Meteor.call, and handle the rest inside the callback?

Comment: Thank you for reply, i adding my story to post!